# Remove background of UIVIew - Remove The rectangle like shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView in which i want to remove the whole background so it would take the shape of a paper. I tried setting the background to transparent from the UI and using the code but i always end up with a gray-like semi transparent background no matter what i do. Here is the current output i am getting : [image]

How can i remove that grey background? i need it to display as a whole paper without that residue. Any Help? I tried the following :

```
//     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//
//     [self.view setOpaque:YES];
//     
   //  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];.
   //  self.view.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    // self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
  //   self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.0];
```

And the current UI Configuration is : 
[image]

How can i manage to remove it !? Any help!?

**EDIT 1**
This is the new output 
[image]

Comment: I think what you're after is image masking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488734/ios-sdk-image-masking

Comment: i think the problem is that the image itself has a gray background. you will have to remove it with an image editing program before importing it into xcode as a .png with an alpha channel. you can send me that image if you like and i'll edit it for you!

Comment: @Zhang i tried to follow it but i need more details, it's my first time with this workaround...can u help out?

Comment: @AndreSlotta thank you so much ! but i am sure that it doesn't have a grey-like background i exported it from illustrator as png and made sure no background was there..what do u think is causing that problem?

Comment: quick and dirty: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eof8rc5t0vcp34d/paper.png?dl=0 - when i put that image inside an uiimageview (without any more customization like background color or something) it just works!

Comment: @AndreSlotta i tried it...same result :( what am i missing

Comment: wanna share your project so i can take a look?

Comment: i wish i could :S it's a company's project i can't share it :S:S @AndreSlotta

Comment: Did you check your `window` background color?

Comment: @AnushaK can you be more specific? where to check?

Comment: Try to set `clearColor` as window background color in appDelegate..

Comment: I already tried it @AnushaK still no results

Comment: oh wait... your image is inside an imageview, right? is it possible that the imageview has a background color set? if so try to set its background color to clear color!

Comment: Where you set this image? In UIView as background color or you have imageView?

Comment: @AnushaK i set it in a uiimageVIew

Comment: @AndreSlotta from the UI i set the UiimageView's Background to clear color and still the same...

Comment: that is really weird. isn't it possible that you just share a storyboard with just the problematic viewcontroller in it? and the class itself of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your image it's inside a Modal View. If that is the case try the following:

Set the `self.view.superview.backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor];` inside the `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

**Example**

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
     self.view.superview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
     self.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: First yes it is in a Modal View, a popup, Second the BackGround did change for the first time !! still not the desired result but i guess it's really close !! can you please check edit 1 to see the new output !? what can i do !?

Comment: It worked ! if only i change self.view.superview.layer.masksToBounds = YES; and put it to self.view.superview.layer.masksToBounds = NO; It will get the needed effect.. Many Thanks!